# Does the compiler optimizes anonymous classes which do not add / override methods?

Tags: java, android, coding-style

I was wondering if the compiler (ECJ, javac, or you can name your favourite compiler) optimizes anonymous classes which do not add or override methods of it's base class.

For example, for code that looks like this:

<sub>Snippet A:</sub>

```
Human h = new Human("John", 30);
h.setX(12.5);
h.setY(15.3);
//..
Eat(h);
```

I'd always prefer the syntax:

<sub>Snippet B:</sub>

```
Eat(new Human("John", 30){
    {
        setX(12.5);
        setY(15.3);
        //..
    }
});
```

However I understand that unlike the `WITH` keyword we have in vb.net, this is not just syntax sugar. What we are telling the compiler to do is to create an anonymous subclass of Human whose constructor consists of the code within the bracers (which is also why we can't use this syntax-sugar for final classes).

The problem now is that I use this syntax-sugar *all the time* (like for example overriding onclick in UI listeners etc), it's like one of my coding style/habits.

Hence the question:

1. Does the compiler optimizes this kind of syntax? (i.e. it realised that no anonymous classes needs to be generated, and the performance of *Snippet B* would be the same as *Snippet A*)
2. If the answer to (1) is "no", I was wondering is it (the *more-than-expected* abundance of anonymous classes due to this coding style) a noticeable impact such that it is highly recommended that for future projects (coding applications for the average **mobile** device) we should always adhere to the style in *Snippet A* ?

Comment: I don't have any insight into how the compiler will handle it unfortunately. But you could write yourself a loop that does it both ways lots of times and take measurements to see the performance implications of both.

Comment: @Tim Yes but the only thing is that it isn't accurate at all to do tests like this. For example, in a real application this kind of code wouldn't be run in a loop in a section of the code, but rather in bits and pieces around the *whole* code right from the start of the app's lifetime to the end of the app's lifetime (it's analogous to our usage of `if` and `else` statements in bits and pieces of the *whole* code instead of say, like in a loop)

Comment: Just a side-note: You're not defining an constructor, but an initializer block. These block are executed _before_ the constructor! So you can't depend that other fields are already created using this approach

Comment: I have struggled with that and used classes like that frequently, but lately i am settling either for setters that return `this` instead of `void` so you can chain them or a Builder pattern. With chaining you could do Eat(new Human("John", 30).setX(12.5).setY(15.3));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will (always) generate an anonymous class (called Human$1). You can see this by examining the class files that are output. You should have a Human.class and Human$1.class as output.

As for performance implications, there will be two classes (bigger, more work for the VM), references from one to the other (because the anonymous inner class will have a link to the outer class). This may have a effect on performance, I suppose, but only minor. You'd have to test it.

However, it's not particularly idiomatic java to do it this way. The idiomatic way would be to have another constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will create a separate binary class.

For instance if you have

```
class Foo{

}

class Bar{
  Foo otherFoo = new Foo(){

  }
}
```

In your bin/target directory you will have three classes

- Bar.class
- Bar$1.class
- Foo.class

Here the anonymous subclass is `Bar$1.class`